# Merge rows to dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes. The big dataframe has many columns such as

```
Sample Gene P.Value Q value 
patient1 Gene1 0.05 0.03
patient1 Gene2 0.05 0.02
patient2 Gene2 0.05 0.03
patient3 Gene1 0.05 0.03
patient3 Gene3 0.05 0.03
```

Df2 looks like following

```
Sample Gene
patient1 gene_a
patient1 gene_b
patient2 gene_b
patient3 gene_a
```

How can i add the rows of the second dataframe Df2 to first dataframe in a way that in other columns it might show NA. I am looking for following output

```
Sample Gene P.Value Q value 
patient1 Gene1 0.05 0.03
patient1 Gene2 0.05 0.02
patient1 gene_a NA NA
patient1 gene_b NA NA
patient2 Gene2 0.05 0.03
patient2 gene_b NA NA
patient3 Gene1 0.05 0.03
patient3 Gene3 0.05 0.03
patient3 gene_a NA NA
```

My original bifg dataframe has around 150 columns and 900 rows just FYI.

Comment: dplyr::bind_rows() should do it, then dplyr::arrange() by Sample

Answer (score 0):

Look at dplyr `bind_rows`: `dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)`